# Crystal report copy to output directory set to copy always

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

i am using crystal report in vb.net however every time i've create a new crystal report in my project solution the property of my crystal report is always set to 'Do not Copy'. My question is, is there any way that if i create a new crystal report the properties of it will always set to copy always so that it will lesser my time work.

if there is any step or strategy on how to do it please share it.
thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think that is the default value of crystal report every time you create it. i don't know if there is a solution but in my case i always click the properties of my crystal report file and change it to copy always.

i can suggest to your question is just patience.